# progress openedge error 215 (create in for each block)

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I'm trying to write code for this scenario:
Go through every customer (customer table) to see if they were members year 2018 (I find that info in the membership table, year field). If there is not a membership that year I want to create it (create customer).

My coding skills aren't great. I get error message 215 (not sure I can translate, but basically: create cannot be done on a 'each' modified post, something like that...).

This is the code I have tried:

```
FOR EACH customer NO-LOCK,
  EACH membership:
    IF CAN-FIND (FIRST membership WHERE membership.year = 2019) THEN DO:
      LEAVE.
    END.
    ELSE DO:
    CREATE membership.
      ASSIGN membership.year = 2018
             .... fill the rest of the table....
   END.
 END.
```

Obviously I am doing it wrong. Suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Comment: It is always helpful to post the precise error message rather than a translation or paraphrasing.  There are often subtle details in the body of the message that can be very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problem is figuring out how customer and membership are related.

For the sake of discussion I am assuming that they have a "custNum" field in common.

In that case something like this ought to work:

```
for each customer no-lock:

  if not can-find( membership where membership.year = 2018 and membership.custNum = customer.custNum ) then
    do:

      create membership.
      assign
        membership.year = 2018
        membership.custNum = customer.custNum
        /* whatever... */
      .

    end.

end.
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You were quite right, of course there was a common cust.num and your code solved the problem.

Comment: It is traditional to mark the answer as correct if it has solved the problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

Tom's answer is correct in that it fixes your code and you don't get the error anymore.
I will try to do explain the error message.
The error message is

```
** CREATE cannot be processed for an EACH mode record--<table>. (215)
```

In this case this means that you are having the CREATE membership statement inside the EACH membership loop. If the rest of the code were correct, the solution would be to use a different buffer for the CREATE. That would change your code into the following (which is still totally wrong but should probably get rid of the compile error):

```
define buffer bmembership for membership.

FOR EACH customer NO-LOCK,
  EACH membership:
    IF CAN-FIND (FIRST membership WHERE membership.year = 2019) THEN DO:
      LEAVE.
    END.
    ELSE DO:
    CREATE bmembership.
      ASSIGN bmembership.year = 2018
             .... fill the rest of the table....
   END.
 END.
```

Comment: Thank you for that explination, very helpful,!